# Как программно сделать изображение в imageview чёрно-белым?

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, android-imageview

Как можно сделать изображение, которое используется в `ImageView`, чёрно-белым?

Comment: Делаете чернобелое изображение и добавляете в ресурсы. Потом програмно меняете изображение с цветного на чернобелое. Или у Вас другая задача?

Comment: Изображение большое, и смена ресурсов вызывает outofmemory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);

ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
imageview.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Kotlin версия:

```
imageView.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(ColorMatrix().apply { setSaturation(0f)})
```

Подразумевается, что изображение задано либо программно, либо через Xml:

```
android:src="@drawable/image_id"
```

Comment: Не работает, увы

Comment: @Lms дайте ссылку на изображение, пожалуйста, у мея сработало

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WagLB-zRbX8Hp1C8X_zbHMHSu7wMTsw4/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Lms изображение через Xml задается? И Вы на Kotlin пишете?

Comment: @Lms У меня с Вашим изображением все работает, проверьте, что Ваш ImageView не null

Comment: Заработало, нужно было использовать src, а у меня в качестве background стояло изображение, спасибо